# Issue collecting a coroutine flow when applying a combine transformation on fragment created

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I am having a strange issue with coroutine flows. I have two flows that i need to observe and if one of them emits a value, collect both flows and perform some transformations based on business logic to emit one result which is the result i am interested in collecting from the fragment. Currently, i am doing this combine in the viewmodel like this

```
//Done in viewmodel
val someComparisonValue = 2
val combinedFlow = firstFlow.combineTransform(secondFlow) { value1, value2 ->
    if (value1 != someComparisonValue) {
      emit(someValueComputed)
    }else if (value1 == value2){
      emit(AnotherValue)
    }
// if none of these conditions are met, emit the first value instead
     emit(value1)
}
// done in fragment
lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
           view.combinedFlow.collect {
               Log.e("Logged", it.toString())
}
```

My issue is that this does not get collected when the fragment gets created even though the two flows already have values emitted as they are connected to a broadcast channel. The transformation does however happen when the fragment has already been created and another emission has been sent. The weird part is without the conditional logic within the `combineTransform`, the fragment will always get the value on create. It seems the doing the conditional logic is not something it executes on create. Does someone have a clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, somehow using broadcast channels was the root cause of the issue. For some reason, emissions were probably dropped so the flow would not be triggered. Switching to ConflatedBroadcastChannels solved this issue for me

Comment: Why did switching to Conflated broadcast channel work?

Comment: @ArunL since i was collecting from multiple viewmodels and fragments, ConflatedBroadcastChannel worked for me because it sends the latest emission to both current and future subscribers, in which case the fragment i was having trouble with was the "future" subscriber